# Autocorrelation in observational data

Tags: least-squares, autocorrelation

I have 10 years of yearly data for 30 baseball teams, 300 cases. I would like to predict team performance based on the different team attributes. For example, I am predicting wins, based on team attributes (i.e, total number of Homeruns in a year for a team) as independent variables. I am not including time as a variable, all 300 cases are being used as though they were 1 period observations. Is this a legitimate thing to do considering the statistics are actually over 10 years?
If I run a Durbin-Watson test to test for autocorrelation, is this really meaningful if I run over all teams (versus within team changes)? I am unclear if I have to consider autocorrelation here.
Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring calendar effects is only legitimate if there truly are no calendar effects. You can easily check this assumption with trend plots.

The Durbin Watson test will be meaningful if you calculate residuals correctly. Like the issue of calendar effects, ignoring team and player effects is only appropriate if there truly are no team and player effects. Again this can be checked using descriptive statistics (ICC), plots, and models. Even if the effects are minimal, you can condition them out with a mixed effects model. Fixed or random effects may be included to control for team and player effects. Ignoring those effects and running Durbin Watson on the naive mean difference values treated as residuals would not be meaningful.